# the phrase " Spare"

Tags: phrases

If I want to say, "refrain your heart from pain" by using the word "spare" do I say "spare your heart from pain" or "spare your heart with pain"?

Comment: Spare your heart *from* pain.

Comment: ... or spare yourself pain (doesn't sound idiomatic with 'heart').

Comment: What you would never say is “Refrain your heart from pain,” which makes no sense.

Comment: You could, however, say "refrain from causing your heart pain."

Comment: The verb *refrain* is not transitive nowadays. We cannot "refrain {something}".  It is intransitive.  We "refrain from {something}".  We elect not to do {something}.

Comment: _Spare_ in this construction is not a phrase but a verb, being used in a verb phrase. _Refrain_ does not take a direct object (like "your heart"); it can appear without an object but with a _from_ prepositiional phrase. _Spare_ and _refrain_ don't mean the same thing, though both have to do with protection.

Answer (score 2):

Neither really works, but if I really had to go with 'spare your heart' I would go with 'spare your heart from the/this pain' or just 'spare your heart the pain'
In most cases you simply name the object - in this case pain
Cambridge Dictionaries online has: Spare - to prevent someone from having to experience something unpleasant: Luckily, I was spared the embarrassment of having to sing in front of everyone. It was a nasty accident - but I'll spare you (= I won't tell you) the gruesome details.
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/spare